# What can I do to fix the following errors which aren't letter me pass the boot screen

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, lubuntu

I just installed Lubuntu on my HP Z2 G9 Workstation (i5 12400, RTX 4060, it came with Windows 10 preinstalled, but I was done with Windows.). Once the Lubuntu installation was finished and the system restarted the PC got stuck at this screen.

[image: boot screen]

Nothing changed even after I left it for a few minutes. I tried to fix the error and I was able to fix the nouveau error by blacklisting it and installing the better CUDA drivers which didn't throw errors (from the grub boot menu), but I couldn't fix the above errors. (The nouveau error was also fixed when I installed Ubuntu with the checkbox for the proprietary drivers.)

Comment: Does this show the nVidia driver? `dkms status` If nVidia installer you should not be using nouveau. The other ACPI errors just about everyone has and are not critical. The tpm may be an UEFI setting which you can change to see it it is resolved.